# How do I bubble up an error from react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have one functional component where I call a methd from another .js file. The method inside the .js file throws an error (which is OK, for my testing purposes), but I want to bubble this error up to the method inside the functional component. How do I do that?

```
import {
  pickImageAsync,
} from "./someFile";

export default class Component1 extends React.Component<any> {
  render() {
    const {  sendError } = this.props;

    function pickImage() {
      try {
        //calling from another file
        pickImageAsync(onSend);
      } catch (error) {
        //I dont reach this part of the file
        console.log("I am catching error: ", error);
        sendImageError(true);
      }
    }
```

In my file `someFile.js`:

```
export async function pickImageAsync(onSend) {
  if (await getImagePickerPermissionAsync()) {
    let result;
    try {
      //with the way I test it this method throws the error, which I want to bubble up
      result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        quality: 1,
      });
      //with the way I test it, I dont see any result, which is OK for my testing purposes
      console.log(result);
       // I dont reach this peace of code which is fine
       if (!result.cancelled) {
             onSend([{ image: result.uri }]);
       }
    } catch (error) {
      //I am catching the error and I see it on the console, but how do I bubble it up?
      console.log("could not select image: ", error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `throw` this error (`throw error`). This will bubble it up in the call stack until someone is catching it (or not and you will see an error in console).

Look at the last line I added:

```
export async function pickImageAsync(onSend) {
  if (await getImagePickerPermissionAsync()) {
    let result;
    try {
      //with the way I test it this method throws the error, which I want to bubble up
      result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        quality: 1,
      });
      //with the way I test it, I dont see any result, which is OK for my testing purposes
      console.log(result);
       // I dont reach this peace of code which is fine
       if (!result.cancelled) {
             onSend([{ image: result.uri }]);
       }
    } catch (error) {
      //I am catching the error and I see it on the console, but how do I bubble it up?
      console.log("could not select image: ", error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```